# Cannot write in matrix <vector<vector<double>> object

Tags: c++, matrix, stl

I created a matrix class by using a vector< vector  >
structure. When created, the matrix is filled with zeroes (probably not the best way to do it, I'm planning to change it).
The header of the class goes something like this:

```
class Matrix{
public:
    /*Basic constructor, accepts matrix dimensions
    Matrix(int nr, int nc);

    /*return element i,j*/
    double elem(int i, int j);

    /*operator () overloading - same thing as previous method*/
    double operator()(int i, int j);

private:
    vector<vector<double> > Matrix_;
    int nr_, nc_;
};
```

while the implementation is:

```
//CONSTRUCTOR
Matrix::Matrix(int nrows, int ncols)
    {
    nc_ = ncols;
    nr_ = nrows;

/*creates rows*/
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        {
        vector<double> row;
        Matrix_.push_back(row);
        }
/*Fills matrix with zeroes*/
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < nc_; j++)
            {
            Matrix_[i].push_back(0);
            }
        }

    }

/*method returning i,j element of the matrix (I overloaded () to do the same)*/
double Matrix::elem(int i, int j)
    {
    return Matrix_[i][j];
    }


/*operator () overloading*/
double Matrix::operator()(int i, int j)
    {
    return Matrix_[i][j];
    }
```

Finally, in the main program I have:

```
Matrix m1(rows, cols);
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
    for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
        m1(i,j) = i*j;
        /*OR, using the other method*/
        m1.elem(i,j) = i*j;
        }
    }
```

and the problem is that I am always returned the error:

```
matrix.cpp:55:27: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
m1.elem(i,j) = i*j;
```

no matter if I am using the method .elem() or the operator ().
So, I guess the problem is that I am not accessing the elements the proper way to change their values, but I don't understand why.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to return a reference `double& Matrix::operator()(int i, int j)`. Same for `Matrix::elem`

Comment: [OT] Your constructor might be simplified to: `Matrix::Matrix(int nrows, int ncols) : Matrix_(nrows, std::vector<double>(ncols, 0.)), nr_(nrows), nc_(ncols) {}`

Comment: [OT]: `nr_` and `nc_` are unneeded, `Matrix_.size()` and `Matrix_[0].size()` has same info. (unless you flatten your data with a unique `std::vector<double(nrows * ncols, 0.)>` and computing indexing manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to modify a matrix element you need to return a reference to it:

```
double& Matrix::elem(int i, int j) {
    return Matrix_[i][j];
}
```

and:

```
double& Matrix::operator()(int i, int j) {
    return Matrix_[i][j];
}
```

You can also add these for `const` matrices:

```
double Matrix::elem(int i, int j) const {
    return Matrix_[i][j];
}
```

and:

```
double Matrix::operator()(int i, int j) const {
    return Matrix_[i][j];
}
```